# XML Layout overlap

Tags: android, layout

I  am trying to create a certain layout, that consists of 2 parts a scrollview and a "footer" at the bottom, but always on top of the scrollview. Everything inside the scrollview must be visible (by scrolling).

[image: example]

This is my current code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/banner" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:layout_height="3px"
    android:background="#DADADA" />

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:text="Start Connecting" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button01"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:text="First use" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:text="Welcome to ADB Wireless!"
       android:textSize="25sp" />

   </RelativeLayout>



 </LinearLayout>
```

But it gives an overlap on small screens & landscape mode. I would only like to have the 2 buttons to be inside the 'footer'. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Previous" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout" >
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```